# the correct usage of `LDFLAGS` in makefile

Tags: makefile

First, the makefile in question roughly looks like this (I'm writing off my memory):

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11 -O3
LDFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++11 -O3

all: clean car.out

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.out


car.out: a.o b.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^

a.o: a.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $<

b.o: b.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $<
```

Basically this will make some object files first and then link them together. I think this is semantically unreasonable because:

1. As its name suggests, `LDFLAGS` is for `ld`, but there is no flags for it here. If we need some external library like OpenGL, then a flag like `-LGL` is passed to `g++`, and then `g++` would pass it to the linker. In that case, it would be reasonable to put `-LGL` in `LDFLAGS`.
2. Even if it's the case where we put flags such as `-Wall` into `LDFLAGS`, it doesn't make much sense. This kind of flags are intuitively for the compilation process, not linking (unless I understand this process wrong).
3. In https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html, there is a piece of code `$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)`, which passes `-c` explicitly. I think this is the better way to do this--putting all compilation flags (e.g. `-Wall`) into `CXXFLAGS`, and pass in `-c` explicitly for object file compilation. Of course, the web page does not say that this piece of code is definitely better or the only way to do it.

So the only reason I can think of to use `LDFLAGS` there is because "there's a linking step," which doesn't make much sense to me. In my opinion, the makefile above should look like:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++11 -O3

all: clean car.out

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.out


car.out: a.o b.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^

a.o: a.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

b.o: b.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<
```

`LDFLAGS` defaults to an empty string, so we can still have it there for the linking step.

However I'm not sure if I'm right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that compilation flags have nothing to do in `LDFLAGS`. Just define `LDFLAGS` explicitly so that another editor -or yourself, when some time has passed- can figure out at a glance that 1. it is empty and 2. where to modify it (like adding `-s` to it, which is quite common).